# Как скомпилировать модуль ядра в Linux?

Tags: linux, драйвер

Мне нужно использовать библиотеки перечисленные ниже для работы с прерываниями на beaglebone но этих библиотек нету подскажите что нужно сделать чтобы их добавить

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/io.h>
#include <asm/exception.h>
#include <linux/irqchip.h>
#include <linux/irqdomain.h>
#include <linux/of.h>
#include <linux/of_address.h>
#include <linux/of_irq.h>
#include <linux/irqchip/irq-omap-intc.h>
```

Установил пакеты `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
пытаюсь сделать Makefile чтобы все это заработало но познание в make небольшие скажите в чем ошибка

```
  CC = gcc

obj-m += ex.o

LIB += -I /usr/include/

all:

        make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.108-ti-r104 M=$(PWD) modules
        make -C /usr/include
ex.o: ex.c
        $(CC) -c ex.c $(LIB)

clean:

        make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.108-ti-r104 M=$(PWD) clean
```

выдает следующие ошибки

```
# make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.108-ti-r104 M=/ modules

make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.108-ti-r104'

  CC [M]  //ex.o

//ex.c:3:9: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

     #include <stdlib.h>

compilation terminated.

scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '//ex.o' failed

make[2]: *** [//ex.o] Error 1

Makefile:1535: recipe for target '_module_/' failed

make[1]: *** [_module_/] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.108-ti-r104'

Makefile:7: recipe for target 'all' failed

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: скачать, и прописать путь в настройках компилятора. По идее #include заработает

Comment: Компилировать модули ядра надо специфическим образом. Это не библиотеки.

Comment: @Dmitry, вы вообще не о том.

Comment: @0andriy а как?) интересно ж

Comment: @0andriy можете сказать как это сделать

Comment: Если коротко, то вам нужны исходники ядра, из которых оно собиралось, там будут соответствующие заголовочные файлы. Соответственно сама сборка запускается командой *make -C /path/to/kernel/sources M=$PWD modules* при условии старта в каталоге исходников модуля.

Comment: @eri, ну вы-то не первый день здесь, могли бы уже и нагуглить -- в интернете полно статей и примеров.

Comment: то есть linux-headers где в приципе это есть выудить нельзя?

Comment: @0andriy пока без надобности, просто праздный интерес

Comment: Заголовки ядра делятся на две категории, а именно для программ в пространстве пользователя (пакет `linux-headers` в некоторых дистрибутивах) и для программ в пространстве ядра (пакет `kernel-sources` в RedHat и клонах).  Для кода, приведённого в посте, нужен пакет для ядра.

Comment: понятно спасибо большое за разъяснение я пытаюсь написать make можете сказать в чем ошибка

Comment: Думаю, в том, что для модуля ядра функции стандартной библиотеки недоступны (а вы пытаетесь инклюдить её заголовок ).

Comment: тогда такой вопрос, если я скомпилирую сначала модули ядра, а потом отдельно подключу с компилированное к коду где использую стандартные библиотеки, так можно делать или нельзя